# sum footer in backgridjs

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, backgrid

I have a backgridjs table below.

```
var columns = [{
    name: "_id",
    label: "account#",
    editable:"false",
    cell: "string"
  }, {
    name: "class",
    label: "class",
    editable:"false",
    cell: "string"
  },{
    name: "date",
    label: "Date",
    editable:"false",
    cell: "string"
  },{
    name: "id",
    label: "id",
    editable:"false",
    cell: "string"
  },{
    name: "total",
    label: "Total",
    editable:"false",
    cell: Backgrid.NumberCell.extend({
      orderSeparator: ','
    }),
    cell: "number"
  }];

var PageableTerritories = Backbone.PageableCollection.extend({
  model: Territory,
  url: "/payroll",
  state: {
    pageSize: 15
  },
  mode: "client" // page entirely on the client side
});

var pageableTerritories = new PageableTerritories();

var CaptionFooter = Backgrid.Footer.extend({
  render: function () {
    this.el.innerHTML = '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>'
    return this;
  }
});

// Set up a grid to use the pageable collection
var pageableGrid = new Backgrid.Grid({
  columns: [{
    // enable the select-all extension
    name: "",
    cell: "select-row",
    headerCell: "select-all",
  }].concat(columns),
  collection: pageableTerritories,
  footer: CaptionFooter // <--
});

// Render the grid
var $example1 = $("#example-1-result");
$example1.append(pageableGrid.render().el)

// Initialize the paginator
var paginator = new Backgrid.Extension.Paginator({
  collection: pageableTerritories
});

// Render the paginator
$example1.after(paginator.render().el);

// Initialize a client-side filter to filter on the client
// mode pageable collection's cache.
var filter = new Backgrid.Extension.ClientSideFilter({
  collection: pageableTerritories,
  fields: ['_id',"Order Class","techId"],
  placeholder: "search"
});

// Render the filter
$example1.before(filter.render().el);

// Add some space to the filter and move it to the right
$(filter.el).css({float: "right", margin: "20px"});

// Fetch some data
pageableTerritories.fetch({reset: true});
```

Everything works great and as expected, except I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set a total footer cell for the total column.

If I type the command below in the console I get the footer cell I want with the total.

```
for (var i = 0,total = 0, len = pageableTerritories.toJSON().length; i < len; ++i) {
  total = total + pageableTerritories.toJSON()[i].total;
  $('tfoot').text(total)
};
```

But I want the the footer cell to show up when the table is rendered. I have tried the following but total shows $0.

```
var CaptionFooter = Backgrid.Footer.extend({

  render: function () {
   for (var i = 0,total = 0, len = pageableTerritories.toJSON().length; i < len; ++i) {
      total = total + pageableTerritories.toJSON()[i].total;
      $('tfoot').text(total)
    };
    this.el.innerHTML = '<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>' + total <---- $0 here
    return this;
  }

});
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone can help me figure this one out. Like always thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please provide a sample on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I had a hard time getting my code to run on jsfiddle. I tried this instead which is http://jsfiddle.net/fpena06/YNy6S/ very similar and the footer works. But my original code doesn't

Comment: I think my problem has to due with the loading of my scripts but I'm not even sure how to begin to debug. I have <script src="rowclick.js"></script> in the body of my page. This is the last script in the body tag which simply handles $("tr").click and console.log('clicked') when I copy the code and paste in the console it works, but not by simply loading the page. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue with the footer total, however when I paginate footer total doesn't update.

```
var PageableTerritories = Backbone.PageableCollection.extend({
  model: Territory,
  url: "/payroll",
  total: function() {
      return this.reduce(function(memo, value) {
        return memo + value.get("total");
      }, 0);
    },
  state: {
    pageSize: 15
  },
  mode: "client" // page entirely on the client side
});

var CaptionFooter = Backgrid.Footer.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this);
      this.collection.bind('sync', this.total);
    },
    total: function(evt) {
      var total = evt.total()
      this.$el.html("<tr><td colspan='7' class='text book bold align right'>Gross Pay: $" + total + "</td></tr>");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Doesn't work anymore because _.bindAll evolved https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder/issues/142

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this simple wrapper around the Backgridjs Footer to provide a Totals Footer.

https://bitbucket.org/base79/backgridjs-total-footer/overview

For your example, update columns to include:

```
var columns = [{
    ...
    {
        name: 'total',
        label: 'Total',
        ...
        footerCell: TotalFooter.Cell.extend({
            getValue: function () {
                return '$' + this.formatter.fromRaw(this._sumColumn());
            }
    })
}];
```

Then pageableGrid becomes:

```
var pageableGrid = new Backgrid.Grid({
  columns: [{
    // enable the select-all extension
    name: "",
    cell: "select-row",
    headerCell: "select-all",
  }].concat(columns),
  collection: pageableTerritories,
  footer: TotalFooter.Footer
});
```

Comment: sorry but I get errors with this. fromRaw of undefined.

Comment: @fpena06 this has fixed now per [this commit](https://bitbucket.org/base79/backgridjs-total-footer/commits/260dc92c6dd1c256e075940d046b3bc17ecaa32f). The problem was that the select-all extension didn't have a formatter, so we now default to a plain Cell formatter. Good luck.

Comment: the commit fixed the error, however I don't see a footer and when I type $('tfoot'); I get `<tfoot><tr><td class="select-row-cell"></td><td class="string-cell _id"></td><td class="string-cell Order Class"></td><td class="string-cell date"></td><td class="string-cell Id"></td><td class="number-cell total">$0.00</td></tr></tfoot>`

Comment: sounds like you're missing a collection event listener somewhere.